# pandas: how to groupby / pivot retaining the NaNs? Converting float to str then back to float works but seems convoluted

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, nan

I am tracking in which "month" a certain event has taken place. If it hasn't, the "month" field is a NaN. The starting table looks like this:

```
+-------+----------+---------+
| Month | Category | Balance |
+-------+----------+---------+
| 1     | a        |     100 |
| nan   | a        |     300 |
| 2     | a        |     200 |
+-------+----------+---------+
```

I am trying to build a crosstab like this:

```
+-------+----------------------------------+
| Month | Category a - cumulative % amount |
+-------+----------------------------------+
|     1 |                             0.16 |
|     2 |                             0.50 |
+-------+----------------------------------+
```

In month 1, the event has happened for 100/600, ie for 16%
In month 2, the event has happened, cumulatively, for (100 + 200) / 600 = 50%, where 100 is in month 1 and 200 in month 2.

**My issue is with NaNs. Pandas automatically removes NaNs from any groupby / pivot / crosstab**. I could convert the month field to string, so that grouping it won't remove the NaNs, but then pandas sorts by the month as if it were a string, ie it would sort: 10, 48, 5, 6.

Any suggestions?

The following works but seems extremely convoluted:

- Convert "month" to string
- Do a crosstab
- Convert "month" back to float (can I do it without moving the index to a column, and then the column back to the index?)
- Sort again
- Do the cumsum

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
mylen = int(10e3)
df['ix'] = np.arange(0,mylen)
df['amount'] = np.random.uniform(10e3,20e3,mylen)
df['category'] = np.where( df['ix'] <=4000, 'a','b' )
df['month'] = np.random.uniform(3,48,mylen)
df['month'] = np.where( df['ix'] <=1000, np.nan, df['month'] )
df['month rounded'] = np.ceil(df['month'])

ct = pd.crosstab(df['month rounded'].astype(str) , df['category'], \
                 values = df['amount'] ,aggfunc = 'sum', margins = True ,\
                     normalize = 'columns', dropna = False)
    
# the index is 'month rounded'
ct = ct.reset_index()
ct['month rounded'] = ct['month rounded'].astype('float32')
ct = ct.sort_values('month rounded')
ct = ct.set_index('month rounded')
ct2 = ct.cumsum (axis = 0)
```

Comment: *"My issue is with NaNs being automatically removed from the crosstab/groupby"* doesn't state the desired behavior. You don't want NaN values in 'Month' to be crosstabulated just like any other (numeric) value, just without the unwanted sort you get when you coerce it to string. **Seems you want the Balance for Month==Nan counted towards column-sum, but not to appear in the table.** Right?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
new_df = df.assign(cumulative=df['Balance'].mask(df['Month'].isna())
                                           .groupby(df['Category'])
                                           .cumsum()
                                           .div(df.groupby('Category')['Balance']
                                                  .transform('sum'))).dropna()
print(new_df)
   Month Category  Balance  cumulative
0    1.0        a      100    0.166667
2    2.0        a      200    0.500000
```

---

If you want create a `DataFrame` for each Category you could create a dict:

```
df_category = {i:group for i,group in new_df.groupby('Category')}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Category a - cumulative % amount'] = (
    df.groupby(by=df.Month.fillna(np.inf))
    .apply(lambda x: x.Balance.cumsum().div(df.Balance.sum()))
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
)

df.dropna()

    Month   Category    Balance Category a - cumulative % amount
0   1       a           100     0.166667
2   2       a           200     0.333333
```